# ¿Qué está fallando en este código php para iniciar sesión?

Tags: php

Hace poco hice este código, que me está arrojando el error que pongo a continuación de.

```
 <?php
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "id11242815_root";
    $dbpass = "12345678";
    $dbname = "id11242815_principal";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    if (!$conn)
    (
        die("No hay conexión: " .mysqli_connect_error())
    );

    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email_usuario = '".$email."' and pass_usuario = '".$password."'");
    $nr = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if ($nr == 1)
    (
        //header ("Location: backend.html");
        echo ¡Bienvenido!;
    );

    else if ($nr == 0)
    (
        //header ("Location: submit-fallido");
        echo ¡Uoops! Hubo un error al iniciar sesión;
    );

    ?>
```

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /storage/ssd5/815/11242815/public_html/login.php on line 22**

Agradecería que me ayudasen con eso,
JadeClay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de los `echo`, agrega comillas.
Ejemplo:

```
echo "¡Bienvenido!";

echo "¡Uoops! Hubo un error al iniciar sesión";
```

Otros cambios que veo serian los siguientes:
**- En los `if`:**

```
if (!$conn)
    (
        die("No hay conexión: " .mysqli_connect_error())
    );
```

Cambiarlos a:

```
if (!$conn)
    {
        die("No hay conexión: " .mysqli_connect_error());
    }
```

Quitar los parentesis y utilizar corchetes (Tambien quitar los punto y coma de los `if`), ademas que en la parte de `die();` Te falto un punto y coma.

```
if ($nr == 1)
    {
        //header ("Location: backend.html");
        echo "¡Bienvenido!";
    }

    else if ($nr == 0)
    {
        //header ("Location: submit-fallido");
        echo "¡Uoops! Hubo un error al iniciar sesión";
    }
```

Comment: Buenas, ya lo hice y sigue dando el mismo error :/ ¿Algo más que haya que corregir?

Comment: Que tal, acabo de editar mi respuesta, para ver si funciona los cambios que acabo de hacer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "id11242815_root";
$dbpass = "12345678";
$dbname = "id11242815_principal";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if (!$conn)
(
    die("No hay conexión: " .mysqli_connect_error());
);

$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email_usuario = '".$email."' and pass_usuario = '".$password."'");
$nr = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($nr == 1) {
    //header ("Location: backend.html");
    echo “¡Bienvenido!”;
} else if ($nr == 0) {
    //header ("Location: submit-fallido");
    echo “¡Uoops! Hubo un error al iniciar sesión”;
}
?>
```